# Can GCC not complain about undefined references?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Under what situation is it possible for GCC to **not** throw an "undefined reference" link error message when trying to call made-up functions?

For example, a situation in which this C code is compiled and linked by GCC:

```
void function()
{
    made_up_function_name();
    return;
}
```

...even though `made_up_function_name` is not present **anywhere** in the code (not headers, source files, declarations, nor any third party library).

Can that kind of code be accepted and compiled by GCC under certain conditions, without touching the actual code? If so, which?

Thanks.

EDIT: no previous declarations or mentions to `made_up_function_name` are present anywhere else. Meaning that a `grep -R` of the whole filesystem will **only** show that exact single line of code.

Comment: It can (as long as you're compiling C, not C++). What are you trying to accomplish though?

Comment: I'm not trying to accomplish anything, it's already happening and I'd like to know why it's possible. The made_up_function_name is actually present in the final, linked binary if I use "-g" and edit the file with a text editor.

Comment: As for why, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914589/c-prototype-functions/4914683, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800102/not-including-stdlib-h-does-not-produce-any-compiler-error/4800138#4800138, and probably quite a few more.

Comment: All proposed answers require the function to at least be defined, even if prototype is optional. "made_up_function_name" is not defined nor prototyped anywhere.

Comment: that prevents it from *linking* successfully, but not from compiling.

Comment: What are you trying to build? If it's shared library then this symbol might come from another library that was loaded via `LD_PRELOAD` or `dlopen("somelib.so", RTLD_GLOBAL)`.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to avoid reporting undefined references - using `--unresolved-symbols` linker option.

```
g++ mm.cpp -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files
```

From `man ld`

> **--unresolved-symbols=method**
>
> Determine how to handle unresolved symbols.  There are four
>   possible values for method:
>
> ```
>        ignore-all
>            Do not report any unresolved symbols.
>
>        report-all
>            Report all unresolved symbols.  This is the default.
>
>        ignore-in-object-files
>            Report unresolved symbols that are contained in shared
>            libraries, but ignore them if they come from regular object
>            files.
>
>        ignore-in-shared-libs
>            Report unresolved symbols that come from regular object
>            files, but ignore them if they come from shared libraries.  This
>            can be useful when creating a dynamic binary and it is known
>            that all the shared libraries that it should be referencing
>            are included on the linker's command line.
> ```
>
> The behaviour for shared libraries on their own can also be
>   controlled by the --[no-]allow-shlib-undefined option.
>
> Normally the linker will generate an error message for each
>   reported unresolved symbol but the option --warn-unresolved-symbols can
>   change this to a warning.

Comment: What are the equivalents for `clang`?

Comment: Also: what are the equivalents for `mingw-gcc` ? The option is recognized, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I'm right there with you, @Michael - mine accepts the option but still throws an Undefined Reference error.

Comment: @Stryker2k2 Then I'll be the bearer of bad news: after researching the topic further, Windows does not support libraries with undefined symbols, so that feature just cannot be made available.

Comment: This can be useful in scenarios where you're "forced" to link to an older version of a library but have a newer one that you will be using available on the system, so this way you can let the linker proceed and at runtime everything will still be fine.

Answer (score 4):

If you declare the prototype of the function before using it , it shold compile. Anyway the error while linking will remain.

```
void made_up_function_name();
void function()
{
    made_up_function_name();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Edited question to reflect this: there's absolutely no other mention to the made up function, other than the call line shown in the example.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR** It *can* not complain, but you *don't* want that. Your code will crash if you force the linker to ignore the problem. It'd be counterproductive.

Your code relies on the ancient C (pre-C99) allowing functions to be implicitly declared at their point of use. Your code is *semantically equivalent* to the following code:

```
void function()
{
    int made_up_function_name(...); // The implicit declaration

    made_up_function_name(); // Call the function
    return;
}
```

The linker rightfully complains that the object file that contains the compiled `function()` refers to a symbol that wasn't found anywhere else. You have to fix it by **providing the implementation** for `made_up_function_name()` **or by removing the nonsensical call**. That's all there's to it. No linker-fiddling involved.

Comment: If making a shared library, though, this makes sense.

Comment: It does not make sense at all: symbols that you wish to import aren't undefined, they are just dynamically bound. I doubt very much that you've actually tried it out and can provide some real scenario - think of a series of bash commands that create the sources, compile and link them, and dump the binaries and demonstrate those undefined-at-link-time symbols.

Comment: Let's be civil.  So:  we have libraries that work together:  say, SDL2, and add-on libraries SDL2_ttf, SDL2_image, and SDL2_mixer.  Do each of the add-ons need to link in SDL2?  Wouldn't that give a program that links in all 4 of these libraries, 4 copies of the functions in SDL2?

Comment: Not at all, and it wouldn't get multiple copies whether the libraries where statically or dynamically linked into the resulting executable, with the only limitation that if the add-ons were dynamically linked to SDL2, but SDL2 wasn't dynamically linked to the executable, then the executable itself would need to export SDL2's symbols. This is possible in both PE and ELF, and while it may not be very popular, there are valid use cases for it. Say that you're wrapping Python and want to statically linkit, but still want the users to be able to add their own Python C modules to your application.

Comment: A caveat is that if SDL2_foo are shared modules and link statically to SDL2, then each will carry its own copy of SDL2, and we don't want that of course.

Comment: Perhaps the point of confusion here is that `made_up_function_name` is allowed to be undefined due to dynamic linking: not at all. Dynamic linking means that you link with a stub (import) library, and that library tells the linker what symbols to pull from what dynamically-loaded module. So even though the values (addresses) of the symbols are not known at link time, it is known that they'll be available at runtime - or the loader will abort. If the linker receives neither a static value for the symbol, nor an instruction that it be dynamically determined, then it will validly complain!

Answer (score 3):

When you build with the linker flag `-r` or `--relocatable` it will also not produce any "undefined reference" link error messages.

This is because `-r` will link different objects in a new object file to be linked at a later stage.

Answer (score 2):

And then there is this nastiness with the -D flag passed to GCC.

```
$cat undefined.c
void function()
{
    made_up_function_name();
    return;
}


int main(){
}

$gcc undefined.c -Dmade_up_function_name=atexit
$
```

Just imagine looking for the definition of made_up_function_name- it appears nowhere yet "does things" in the code.
I can't think of a nice reason to do this exact thing in code.

The -D flag is a powerful tool for changing code at compile time.

Comment: The `-D` flag changes code at *compile* time. Then there's stuff like `-Wl,--wrap` which does that at link time.

Comment: And if one combines `-D` with pre-processor token merging then the text `made_up_function_name` need not appear as-such in any makefile or build script either.

Answer (score 1):

If `function()` is never called, it might not be included in the executable, and the function called from it is not searched for either.

Comment: so it might compile even without declaring the prototype and then be linked too? I think that at least the prototype should be declared, otherwise it would generate a parsing error, right?

Comment: @0verbose - It depends on which C standard you use. Originally, prototypes were not needed. And later only if you had parameter types other than int.

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" algorithm according to which POSIX linkers operate leaves open the possibility that the code will compile and link without any errors. See here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894098/187690

In order to exploit that possibility the object file that contains your `function` (let's call it `f.o`) should be placed into a library. That library should be mentioned in the command line of the compiler (and/or linker), but by that moment no other object file (mentioned earlier in the command line) should have made any calls to `function` or any other function present in `f.o`. Under such circumstances linker will see no reason to retrieve `f.o` from the library. Linker will completely ignore `f.o`, completely ignore `function` and, therefore, remain completely oblivious of the call to `made_up_function_name`. The code will compile even though `made_up_function_name` is not defined anywhere.