# cannot import module using boost.python

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I'm trying to build a simple program using boost.python. 
I have the following code:

```
//greet.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

void greet()
{
    std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(greet)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

and the follwing `makefile`:

```
PYTHON_VERSION := 2.7

PYTHON_INC := /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)
PYTHON_LIB_LOCATION := /usr/lib/python${PYTHON_VERSION}
PYTHON_LIB_FILE := python${PYTHON_VERSION}

BOOST_INC := ~/boost_1_54_0
BOOST_LIB_LOCATION := /home/elyashiv/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib
BOOST_LIB_FILE := boost_python

CC := gcc

CFLAGS := -c -fPIC
CInc := -I ${BOOST_INC} -I ${PYTHON_INC}

CLinkFlags = -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -L${BOOST_LIB_LOCATION} -l${BOOST_LIB_FILE} -L${PYTHON_LIB_LOCATION} -l${PYTHON_LIB_FILE}

greet.o: greet.cpp

%.so: %.o
    gcc ${CLinkFlags} -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${CInc} $^
```

running `make greet.so` runs with just a few warnings (redefinition in some boost files).

when I try to import the module in python I get the following:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 05:46:21) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import greet
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./greet.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv
```

what I have done wrong and how to fix it?

**edit**

the output of `ldd greet.so`:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x001ee000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0055d000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0058e000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x003a2000)
```

Comment: If you are on Linux, could you also paste the output of `ldd greet.so`? Does that show your boost_python library linked in?

Comment: Where is `libboost_python`? It is not getting linked in, therefore, you have the missing symbol. Make sure your compilation is working as expected.

Comment: @AndréAnjos as I wrote, I don't get any compilation/linking errors. If some thing is wrong with the linking process, I will like to point it out, because I can't spot it.

Comment: I just added a full explanation of your problem below, please upvote if you think it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that [order is important](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363398/g-linking-order-dependency-when-linking-c-code-to-c-code) when you are linking binaries with gcc. The order in which you pass binaries to the linker should be such that the first unit (e.g. your object file) should resolve using the **following** units (other object files or libraries). In your example, you are linking `greet.so` wrongly:

```
%.so: %.o
    gcc ${CLinkFlags} -o $@ $^
```

This is going to generate a compilation line like this:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,greet.so -L/usr/lib -lboost_python -L/usr/lib/python2.7 -lpython2.7 -o greet.so greet.o
```

Notice that the unit `greet.o`, which depends on symbols defined in `libboost_python.so` and `libpython2.7.so` is coming last and therefore, by the time gcc's linker gets to it, it cannot resolve the undefined symbols anymore. Unfortunately, this is not an error, because the linker cannot know if you want this or not (for example, in Python, libpythonX.Y will be loaded before you can import your code in and it may be skipped therefore - you can dump that library from your command line altogether). So, the default is to ignore all undefined symbols.

You can change that behavior by setting a couple of flags to force undefined symbol detection:

```
CLinkFlags += -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all
```

Will report all unresolved symbols as errors and:

```
CLinkFlags += -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -Wl,--warn-unresolved-symbols
```

Will report all unresolved symbols but will still link the binary. You have other options explained [on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555632/can-gcc-not-complain-about-undefined-references). **Be warned**: this is not what you normally want. Things like `libpythonX.Y` are never explicitly linked for example, but they are still available at runtime. In practice, you will still get a bunch of fake undefined references that are not worth persuing. The best is to fix your Makefile and make sure your object code comes **before** the libraries.

To fix your example, just move `$^` to the **begin** of the linking like:

```
gcc $^ ${CLinkFlags} -o $@
```

After you compile, and you run `ldd`, you should see that now `libboost_python` (and `python` since you are explicitly linking it) will be linked against `greet.so` and the loading should work as you expect. I tested it myself locally.

As a rule of thumb, if you have undefined references with gcc and you are confident they should be present on any of the linked code, double-check the order.

Here is a fully working/minimal version of your Makefile that will do the job for your specific case (note we also set the runtime path to your private boost library, so you don't need to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as indicated by other answers - see details below):

```
PYTHON_VERSION := 2.7
PYTHON_INC := /usr/include/python$(PYTHON_VERSION)
BOOST_INC := /home/elyashiv/boost_1_54_0
BOOST_LIB_LOCATION := /home/elyashiv/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib
BOOST_LIB_FILE := boost_python

CC := gcc

CFLAGS := -c -fPIC
CInc := -I${BOOST_INC} -I${PYTHON_INC}

CLinkFlags = -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -Wl,-rpath,${BOOST_LIB_LOCATION} -L${BOOST_LIB_LOCATION} -l${BOOST_LIB_FILE}

greet.so: greet.o

%.so: %.o
  gcc $^ ${CLinkFlags} -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
  ${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${CInc} $^
```

By [setting the runtime path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726993/g-how-to-specify-preference-of-library-path) on the library itself, the runtime linker automatically looks there first before trying the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. If you decide not to do so, then you must set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as indicated by other answers.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea there is a meaning to the order.

Comment: Your answer is great, but it still not the end of it. merging your answer with doctorloves answer gt rid from all the errors.

Comment: Ok, I just added a comment indicating how you can do that using the linker itself.

Answer (score 1):

Boost python requires the boost python `so` file. You can add it to your path when you run the python in a variety of ways. I am using

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:../ThirdParty/boost_1_52_0/lib/linux64/
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I run `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:~/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib` and got the same error. I'm using the wrong dir?

Comment: I take it /boost_1_54_0/stage/lib has the boost python so?

Comment: does that mean I cannot use the extension on a machine that doesn't have the boost libs? if not - how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands. These worked for me.

```
g++ -c -I/usr/include/python2.7 -fPIC hello.cpp -o hello.o 
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,"hello.so" -L/usr/local/lib hello.o -lboost_python -fPIC -o hello.so
```