# NDK - How to get "undefined reference" during compile-time?

Tags: android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I am using the standalone toolchain to produce my .so and when I link my .o files to it, I get no "undefined reference" errors because it is creating dependencies that are resolved during runtime.

I would like to resolve all the symbols during the compile-time and get "undefined reference" when symbols aren't resolved. How do I do that?

Comment: Please explain. Do you want your .so file to have no external dependencies at all? Or maybe you want to use static linking to libm and libc? Or simply list all the external references? Also, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568540/how-to-make-gcc-or-ld-report-undefined-symbols-but-not-fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"-z defs" does the job.

Ref.: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld